# Iterate over type of enum parameter

Tags: generics, rust, enums

Is it possible to define a function, which takes any enum value as parameter and then iterates over the type? Something like this pseudo code:

```
#[derive(Display)]
enum Difficulty {
    Easy,
    Middle,
    Hard,
}

fn enum_as_radio_select<T: Enum + Display>(selected: T) {
    for enum_value in T::iter() {
        let is_selected = enum_value == selected;
        let text = enum_value.to_string();
        add_radio_button(is_selected, text);
    }
}

enum_as_radio_select(Difficulty::Easy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`strum`](https://docs.rs/strum) crate has this: [`#[derive(EnumIter)]`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.EnumIter.html) (note you need to activate the `derive` feature):

```rust
#[derive(strum::EnumIter, Display, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Difficulty {
    Easy,
    Middle,
    Hard,
}

fn enum_as_radio_select<T: Display + strum::IntoEnumIterator + PartialEq>(selected: T) {
    for enum_value in T::iter() {
        let is_selected = enum_value == selected;
        let text = enum_value.to_string();
        add_radio_button(is_selected, text);
    }
}

enum_as_radio_select(Difficulty::Easy);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much. I would also like to mention, that I had to use strum::Display in the attribute of the enum and std::fmt::Display in the generic parameter.